# series of arrays that I need to create by JavaScript and save to my desktop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a series of arrays that I need to create by JavaScript and save to my desktop.

Because there are many arrays, storing these arrays manually takes time for me
Friends, is there a way for JS to save them automatically?

```
let numb = [0, 1, 2, 4] < ==== This array has more than 1000 elements

numb.forEach(e => {
            let dt=[e]
            let newList =  JSON.stringify(dt);
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(newList);
            a.download = e + '.csv';
            a.click();
            console.log(e[0]);


})
```